# Quartz Composer 4k ProRes 422HQ glitches

Tags: macos, video, osx-mavericks, quartz-composer

For a project due to perform soon enough I happen to have a problem. Task is to play 4k PRORES 422 files according to a sequence that is written on a file (XML) while listening on a OSC port for CUE signals and some feedback to the operator. Player also can smooth the speed +- 15% and has a general fader, and sends back to OSC controller few data to update the performer.

The playback is now unpredictably un-smooth And I don't know why.
I also tend to think is not a problem of hardware: Machine used is a mac pro 2014 with 10.9 (https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/specs/) with 64mb Ram, all data on SDD and a hell of a graphic card. The un-smoothness in playback is rather unpredictable, random frame drops in different places. I tried to use external time on the player and is a bit better but still not satisfactory. I am going to package it without the editor in a app, but on preliminary test is not that faster.
I wander also what is the best way to examine the code for leaks...

Playback of files in quicktime player uses 20% of cpu and in quartz composer +90%

I am stuck on this issue, having done all the obvious things I think, and would like at least to understand how to profile the performance of the patch to find what is wrong and were.

Suggestions are welcome and thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If its not interactive you could try rendering it in quicktime player.